# Marching Square algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

The following source code is a solution to the [Marching Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares) problem.

The explanation of using random numbers in ambiguous cases [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62868990/159072).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;

namespace G__Marching_Sqaure
{    
    public static class StaticRandomNumber
    {
        private static Random rnd = new Random();
        public static int GetRandom(int min, int max)
        {
            return rnd.Next(min, max);
        }
    }

    public class Point
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public Point Start { get; set; }
        public Point End { get; set; }

        public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
        {
            Start = new Point(x1, y1);
            End = new Point(x2, y2);
        }

        public Line(Point start, Point end)
        {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }
    }

    public class LinesRectangle
    {
        public Graphics Graphics { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public Pen Pen { get; set; }
        public int Thickness { get; set; }

        public LinesRectangle()
        {
            Color = Color.Blue;
            Thickness = 2;
            Pen = new Pen(Color, Thickness);
        }

        public void DrawLine(Line line)
        {
            Graphics.DrawLine(Pen, line.Start.X, line.Start.Y, line.End.X, line.End.Y);
        }
    }

    public partial class DrawingForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public DrawingForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public int [,] Data { get; set; }

        public void Print(int[,] data, int xn, int yn)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yn; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < xn; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(data[j, i] + ", ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        public int[,] ToBinary(int[,] data, int xn, int yn)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < yn; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < xn; i++)
                {
                    if (data[j, i] > 1)
                    {
                        data[j, i] = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        data[j, i] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            int xWidth = data.GetLength(1);
            int yHeight = data.GetLength(0);

            for (int j = 0; j < yHeight; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < xWidth; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(data[j, i] + ", ");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            return data;
        }

        public Point GetMidPoint(Point thisp, Point other)
        {
            int xHalf = (thisp.X + other.X) / 2;
            int yHalf = (thisp.Y + other.Y) / 2;

            return new Point(xHalf, yHalf);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Line> GetLines(int casevalue, int[] xVector, int[] yVector, int i, int j)
        {
            List<Line> linesList = new List<Line>();

            Point topLeft = new Point(xVector[i], yVector[j]);
            Point topRight = new Point(xVector[i+1], yVector[j]);
            Point bottomLeft = new Point(xVector[i], yVector[j+1]);
            Point bottomRight= new Point(xVector[i+1], yVector[j+1]);

            if (casevalue == 0) {/*do nothing*/ }
            if (casevalue == 15) {/*do nothing*/ }

            if ((casevalue == 1) || (casevalue == 14))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(topLeft, bottomLeft);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
            }
            /*2==13*/
            if ((casevalue == 2) || (casevalue == 13))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(topRight, bottomRight);
            }
            /*3==12*/
            if ((casevalue == 3) || (casevalue == 12))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(topLeft, bottomLeft);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(topRight, bottomRight);
            }
            /*4==11*/
            if ((casevalue == 4) || (casevalue == 11))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(topLeft, topRight);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(topRight, bottomRight);
            }
            /*6==9*/
            if ((casevalue == 6) || (casevalue == 9))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(topLeft, topRight);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
            }

            /*7==8*/
            if ((casevalue == 7) || (casevalue == 8))
            {
                Point start = GetMidPoint(topLeft, topRight);
                Point end = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
            }

            if ((casevalue == 5) || (casevalue == 10))
            {
                int caseValueTemp = 0;
                int randVal = StaticRandomNumber.GetRandom(1,11);

                if (randVal % 2 == 0)
                {
                    caseValueTemp = 5;
                }
                else
                {
                    caseValueTemp = 10;
                }

                /*ambiguous case*/
                if (caseValueTemp == 5)
                {
                    Point start1 = GetMidPoint(topLeft, bottomLeft);
                    Point end1 = GetMidPoint(topLeft, topRight);
                    Line line1 = new Line(start1, end1);

                    Point start2 = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
                    Point end2 = GetMidPoint(topRight, bottomRight);
                    Line line2 = new Line(start2, end2);

                    linesList.Add(line1);
                    linesList.Add(line2);
                }
                if (caseValueTemp == 10)
                {
                    Point start1 = GetMidPoint(topLeft, topRight);
                    Point end1 = GetMidPoint(topRight, bottomRight);
                    Line line1 = new Line(start1, end1);

                    Point start2 = GetMidPoint(topLeft, bottomLeft);
                    Point end2 = GetMidPoint(bottomLeft, bottomRight);
                    Line line2 = new Line(start2, end2);

                    linesList.Add(line1);
                    linesList.Add(line2);
                }
            }

            return linesList;
        }

        public List<Line> marching_square(int[] xVector, int[] yVector, int[,] imageData, int isovalue)
        {
            List<Line> linesList = new List<Line>();

            int dataWidth = imageData.GetLength(1);
            int dataHeight = imageData.GetLength(0);

            if (dataWidth == xVector.Length && dataHeight == yVector.Length)
            {
                imageData = ToBinary(imageData, dataWidth, dataHeight);

                for (int j = 0; j < dataHeight - 1; j++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataWidth - 1; i++)
                    {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        sb.Append(imageData[j, i]);
                        sb.Append(imageData[j, i + 1]);
                        sb.Append(imageData[j + 1, i + 1]);
                        sb.Append(imageData[j + 1, i]);

                        int casevalue = Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString(), 2);

                        IEnumerable<Line> list = GetLines(casevalue, xVector, yVector, i, j);

                        linesList.AddRange(list);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("dimension mismatch!");
            }

            return linesList;
        }

        private void MainForm_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            int[,] data = new int[,]  {
                                        { 2,1,2,1,2,2,2 },
                                        { 1,2,1,2,1,2,2 },
                                        { 2,1,2,1,2,2,2 },
                                        { 1,2,1,2,1,2,2 },
                                        { 2,1,2,1,2,2,2 }
                                      };
            
            int width = data.GetLength(1);
            int height = data.GetLength(0);
                        
            int[] x = new int[] {0, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600};
            int[] y = new int[] {0, 100, 200, 300, 400};


            int xMaxCoord = x[6];
            int yMaxCoord = y[4];
            int[,] adjacencyMatrix = new int[xMaxCoord, yMaxCoord];

            List<Line> collection = marching_square(x, y, data, 0);

            

            Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();

            LinesRectangle rect = new LinesRectangle();
            rect.Graphics = g;

            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                rect.DrawLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone kindly review this?

---

**N.B.** Kindly, only focus on the algorithm, not class-arrangement.

Comment: TL;DR but few tips: I suggest to use `switch-case` statement instead of `if-if-if`. Also you may use [`yield return`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) to build an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of creating `List` inside. Also `Console.WriteLine` in Winforms app looks odd, for debuggong purpose try `Debug.WriteLine` instead. Also looks like `GetLines()` do nothing for all cases except `5` and `10`.